# Django model cannot find a static file

Tags: django

in my models.py I have (myfile.txt is 3gb)

```
with open('/static/myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
  do something..
```

but it complains

```
No such file or directory: '/static/myfile.txt'
```

this is my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'absolute_dir_to_project/app_name/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should prepend the absolute path with `SETTINGS`'s STATIC_URL so that it looks for `myfile.txt` inside Django:

```
from django.conf import settings # dont forget to import this guy

with open(settings.STATIC_URL + 'myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    do something..
```

Comment: `os.path.join` would probably be better than concatenating the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `open` function is trying to open a file from disk with the path `/static/myfile.txt`, rather than requesting a file through your Django web app. It doesn't sound like you need to have this file in your static files folder, especially if it's huge and isn't intended for public consumption